# Writing HQL for the relationship entities

Tags: hibernate, entity

I am developing an application in struts 2.1 and for database interaction I have used hibernate, in my registration screen  user will enter like firstname,lastname,address and city,city is a dropdown control which gets populated from the database. So therefore user enters all the details and selects city from the dropdown and submits the form which actually saves the data successfully into user table. Here is the code:

Action Class

```
 public class RegisterPartnerAction extends ActionSupport {
    private String firstname
private String lastname;
private String address;
private int city_id;

 //getter and setters firstname,lastname,address and city_id
 //saves the object into db
 User user = new User();
  UserDao userDao = new UserDao();

  user.setfirstname(getfirstname());
  user.setlastname(getlastname());
  user.setaddress(getaddress());
  user.setCity_id(getCity_id());
  userDao.SaveUser(user);
 }
```

Dao Layer

```
 public class UserDao
 {

   public void SaveUser(User user){
    SessionFactory sessionFactory= HibernateManager.getSessionFactory();
     Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
     session.beginTransaction();
     session.save(user);
     session.getTransaction().commit();
     session.close();
}

 }
```

User Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User implements  Serializable {

    @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="user_id")
private int user_id;

    @Column(name="firstname")
private String firstname;

@Column(name="lastname")
private String lastname;

@Column(name="address")
private String address;

@Column(name="city_id")
private int city_id;
   // getter and setter
   }
```

City Entity

```
 @Entity
  @Table(name="city")
  public class City implements  Serializable {

    @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="city_id")
private int city_id;

    @Column(name="cityname")
private String firstname;

@Column(name="city_code")
private String citycode;

   // getter and setter
   }
```

Till saving of the data into user table goes fine. Now if you will see user table or entity is linked with city_id.
Now I want to fetch a particular user along with City detail means cityname, city_code. I do not understand how to write HQL for it

I have tried using below HQL

```
     select ur.firstname,ur.lastname,ur.address,cy.cityname,cy.city_code  from " +
            "User ur,City cy" +
            "where " +
            "ur.city_id=cy.city_id and" +
            "ur.user_id=:<some_hardcoded_id>";
```

This is not working. Please anybody suggest me regarding the way of releationship of the two entities. It would be a great help to me.

Comment: You should not have the ID of another entity (city_id) in an entity (User). Instead, you should have a field of type City, mapped with the @ManyToOne annotation. Associations are a key feature of JPA/Hibernate, and not using them prevents you from using joins in HQL queries. Read the documentation.

Comment: thanks for the help but my problem is that city is a dropdown controll in GUI and when user submits the form he selects any of the city and what i receive in my action class i.e RegisterPartnerAction is the city_id.Can you please elaborate a more that if i use @ManyToOne mapping then how can i save the city_id into my User table

Comment: Use `session.find()` or `session.load()` to find the City with the given ID, and set it as the city of the user.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a proper join your User class should look something like this:

```
public class User {

    // ...

    @ManyToOne
    // @JoinColumn if necessary
    private City city;
}
```

HQL should then look something like this:

```
select ur.firstname,/*..*/cy.cityname,cy.city_code 

from User ur join fetch ur.city 

where ur.user_id = :userId";
```

But since the City is part of the User now, it will probably be sufficient to just fetch the user object

```
from User ur join fetch ur.city 

where ur.user_id = :userId";
```